# Webpack 5: Image src in html when using contentHash

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I am able to get the src attribute correct when importing images in my js files.
But not when specifying img src url in my html code.
How to get the correct url in html automatically whenver i build the project.

```
webpack.config

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "main-page": "./src/scripts/index.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.[name].[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"), 
    publicPath: "static/", 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.hbs$/,
        use: ["handlebars-loader"],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/handlebars/index.hbs",
      filename: "index.html",
    }),
  ],
}
```

```
somefile.js

import Image from "../assests/img.jpg";

const imgEle=document.createElement("img");
imgEle.src=Image; // gets corrrectly refrenced to md5hash.jpg in the bundle
```

```
index.hbs (using handlebars)

<img src="?" /> // what to do here so that it correctly gets refrenced.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make it work you have to configure the option `inlineRequires` of the `hbs` loader which is addressed [here](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader#details).

Here's what you have to refine for both `file-loader` and `handlebars-loader`. Please check the inline comments for both loaders:

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          // Turn off esModule setting 
          options: {
            esModule: false,
          }
        }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.hbs$/,
        use: {
          loader: "handlebars-loader",
          options: {
            // This option tells to to require the assest 
            inlineRequires: '\/assests\/',
          }
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Finally, you simply specify the path to image in your templat.

```html
// index.hbs
// specify the path to asset which must relate to this file (`index.hbs`)
<img src="../assests/img.jpg" />
```